# Count() on blank space XQUERY

Tags: xml, count, xquery

I want to count how many books I have listed
I have:

```
books = "book-one book-two book-three ..."
```

If i use

```
count(books)
```

it only returns 1 no matter how long my string is, since count separates on , I'm guessing.

How can I count separating on blank-space instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the books are separated by a space, you can split the string into a sequence of strings using the `fn:tokenize()` function:

```
fn:tokenize("book-one book-two book-three", " ")
```

This will return a sequence of the books:

```
("book-one", "book-two", "book-three")
```

The `fn:tokenize()` function can work with literal strings like `" "`, or it can take regular expressions like `"\s+"` (to mean "one or more whitespace characters"). This allows for some pretty sophisticated pattern matching.

For the canonical description of this function, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize, and for more on regular expressions in XPath and XQuery, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#string.match.

Comment: Note that the XQuery 1.0 version of the function requires a regular expression as the second argument, and it's best to call `normalize-space()` first to get rid of any leading or trailing whitespace, as the count may otherwise be misleading. XQuery 3.1 has a single-argument `tokenize()` function that tokenizes on whitespace after (effectively) doing an implicit normalize-space().